# Show count of users returning to homepage from within site in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Can anyone advise if the following is even possible using Google Analytics?

I need to show the number of users who enter the site (on any page) but then return up the hierarchy to the home page (either immediately or after visiting other pages).

The requirement is because we've recently had our web site redesigned, but we think the navigation is confusing, and that users are "exiting" the structure to start their search again for their required product/service.  We need concrete numbers facts to support this suspicion!

The closest I can get is via `Audience > User Flow` then manually add up how many times the `/` page is shown on each interaction (after `Starting Pages`, e.g. `2nd Interaction` plus `3rd Interaction`, but its a painfully slow process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should at least partly work with a sequence type segment.

> New segment -> Sequence
>
> *Filter by session*
>
> Step 1: *page matches regexp /.+* (any page with a path longer than /)
>
> *is immediately followed by*
>
> Step 2: *page exactly matches /*

This would filter anybody who looks at the homepage immediately after looking at any other page, but not those who visited another page in between (you could filter by user instead of by session, but that would simply give you the returning users for the selected timeframe).

Comment: That's a big step in the right direction, thank you @Eike.  If I change `is immediate followed by` to `is followed by` would that show all users who eventually ended up back at the first page after a few other pages (which is actually what I need, and would further highlight "lost" visitors)?